# Background image/position rendering differently on iPad

Tags: css, ipad, background-image, background-position

I have a div which has one of two background positions for a sprite background image depending on the class set for the div in a php script.

The CSS, which is below, works fine on standard browsers, but on the iPad I am not seeing the same.  Instead I see more of the background image than I want to.  As you can see from the image below, rather than just seeing one star, I am seeing part of another star too.

How can I get the background position/image looking right on the iPad?

```
.normal, .favourite {
    width:18px;
    height:17px;
    margin-right: 4px;
    border:none;
    cursor: pointer;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color:transparent;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.normal {
    background-image: url('/images/playlist_sprite.png');
    background-position: left bottom;
}

.favourite {
    background-image:url('/images/playlist_sprite.png');
    background-position: right bottom;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Try this css property `background-size: 100% 100%;` in `.normal, .favourite {}` and let me know. Thanks!

Comment: This just shows the whole sprite image, reducing it to fit in 18px by 17px

Answer (score 0):

Rather than defining the background position using left/right/bottom try defining it exactly using pixels.

e.g.

```
background-position: XXpx XXpx;
```

Also, make sure that both those images in your sprite are exactly 18px by 17px as that is what the class is saying the image size will be.

Comment: Thanks. I tried doing this, i.e. background-position: 0px 17px; for .normal and background-position: 18px 17px; for .favourite and then no background image shows at all (on both iPad and normal browsers), which is rather strange. An image only shows if I use top, bottom, left, right, etc.  What could be the cause of this?  Both the images in the sprite are exactly 18px by 17px.

Comment: Can you provide a link to your page or create a fiddle?

Comment: I'll create a fiddle and report back as my site is behind a login

Comment: Mmmh. It looks fine on the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nickharambee/dKAYz/). I presume that it must be some other CSS on the page interfering with the CSS for the stars when using the iPad.

Comment: Does it look okay on the fiddle on the iPad?

Comment: Yes it does. Which suggests the CSS conflict to me. Also using pixels for background-position should work, but doesn't.

Comment: Ah well, not much more we can do unless you can let us see the whole page I guess.